# Swift Realm filter all object with a null value

Tags: swift, realm

I have two objects as follow:

```
class NextAction: Object {
    @objc dynamic var title: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var notes: String? = ""
    @objc dynamic var deadline: Date?
    @objc dynamic var deadlineID: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var reminder: Date?
    @objc dynamic var reminderID: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var finished: Bool = false
    @objc dynamic var favorite: Bool = false
    @objc dynamic var priority: Int = 0
    var duration = RealmOptional<Int>()
    @objc dynamic var tag: String?
    let tags = List<Tag>()
}

class Tag: Object {
    @objc dynamic var title: String = ""
    let owners = LinkingObjects(fromType: NextAction.self, property: "tags")
}
```

Not all NextAction objects has a tag, but I want to filter out and show all who are missing one, I have tried

```
var test = realm.objects(NextAction.self).filter("ANY tags == nil")
```

But I get this error

```
'Invalid value', reason: 'Expected object of type Tag for property 'tags' on object of type 'NextAction', but received: (null)'
```

Comment: `tag` and `tags` are two different properties. Your question states *Not all NextAction objects has a tag* but that appears to be unrelated to the query you're trying to do because you're using `tags` in the query. Also, List properties cannot be nil - it's a list which works like an array and can have a tags count of 0 but not nil. Can you clarify the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `tags` cannot be `nil`. 
If you want to find objects whose `tags` is empty, you can do that this way.

```swift
var test = realm.objects(NextAction.self).filter("ANY tags.@count == 0")
```